# How to find the selected text field in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uistoryboard

I am developing one iPad application using story board.In my application i have popup view with two text fields and one button.what i need to do means if i click the button one text is need to display in the selected text box. How i find which text box is selected at the present situation? Example code is give below Please help me to complete function.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
     if(//Here i need to set the condition for check selected text box is first){
         texbox1.text=@"User";
      }
      else{
         textbox2.text =@"Admin";
      }
}
```

Comment: How can a text field be selected if a button has just been pressed?

Comment: @trojanfoe I Create ib actions for each text fields.and set flag .this method is correct?.Is any short method available?

Comment: Your question is confusing about what you want to achieve.  If the button is pressed then the (previously "selected") text field becomes de-selected.  So explain more clearly please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

   if([textbox1 isFirstResponder]){
       //Cursor on textbox1
       texbox1.text=@"User";
   }
   else if([textbox2 isFirstResponder]){
      //Cursor on textbox2
       textbox2.text =@"Admin";
   }
   else{

       NSLog(@"None of them have cursor");
   }
}
```

Comment: If a button is pressed, doesn't *it* become the first responder?

Comment: @vijay Thank you...Your answer is working for me.I marked as correct answer.

Comment: @trojanfoe so will keyboard will be resigned automatically when we click the button? not!

Comment: @Vijay-Apple-Dev.blogspot.com I put one more Question Would you please help me to solve this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446429/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-when-add-an-unwind-function-to-view-contr

Comment: @Vijay-Apple-Dev.blogspot.com http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376689/cookies-attributes-become-null Help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 4):

1. Set `Tag` to your `textfields`
2. Implement `UITextFieldDelegate` in your class
3. Use this methods

   ```
   - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
       if (textField.tag == your tag) {
           selectedTextField = textField; //selectedTextField is an UITextfield variable
       }
   }
   ```
4. Use it in your `IBAction`

   ```
   - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
       selectedTextField.text = @"abc";
   }
   ```

//Edit: something wrong with StackOverFlow's code function, doesn't display properly

Comment: There are vital details missing from this answer; e.g. setting the delegate and what to do in the delegate method.

Comment: @Pham please explain  your answer. How i set text for field?

Comment: recheck, i mis-clicked post before complete my answer

Comment: +1 I believe this is the correct approach.  When a button is pressed *it* will become the first responder, so solutions which test for the current first responder will fail.  Other notes: You might want to ensure `selectedTextField` is initialised to the first text field when the view is made visible.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think the below code is what you want:-

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    if(self.texbox1.isFirstResponder){
        self.texbox1.text=@"User";
        [self.texbox1 resignFirstResponder];
    }

    if(self.texbox2.isFirstResponder){
        self.texbox2.text=@"Admin";
        [self.texbox2 resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

I am not sure why you want to implement as above though as it is a bit funny.

Comment: If a button is pressed, doesn't *it* become the first responder?

Comment: From what I understand is that he/she wants to display a text on a "selected" text field when a button is pressed. I think what he/she meant by "selected" is the First respondent. Therefore, my answer as above.

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField` is a subclass of `UIResponder` which allows you to perform checks including `isFirstResponder` which may be what you are looking for. However you will need to understand how the responder chain works and if this is really the behavior you are trying to detect.

Answer (score 0):

Use isFirstResponder to check which textbox is active.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
     if([textbox1 isFirstResponder]){
         texbox1.text=@"User";
      }
      else if([textbox2 isFirstResponder]) {
         textbox2.text =@"Admin";
      } else {
         // What should happen when neither textbox1 nor textbox2 is active?
      }
}
```